# What do you call a book full of aphorisms?

Tags: word-request

Most of Nietszche's books are anthologies or compilations of aphorisms. Is there a particular name for such books? I don't think there's any word for it, but I just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a particular name for such books?

That seems very unlikely.

For example, let's say the word you were looking for was "compendium". Then probably at least one of the following would have added that word to their title.

- Oxford Book Of Aphorisms (Oxford Books of Prose) by John Gross
- The Bed of Procrustes: Philosophical and Practical Aphorisms by Nassim Nicholas Taleb
- The Viking Book of Aphorisms by W. H. Auden, Louis Kronenberger
- The Faber Book of Aphorisms: A Personal Selection by W.H. Auden, Louis Kronenberger
- Everything: A Book of Aphorisms by Aaron Haspel
- Geary's Guide to the World's Great Aphorists by James Geary